# Reading a cookie that contains an array

Tags: php, cookies

I have a cookie set in the format:

`{"necessary":true,"functional":true,"advertising":false,"performance":true,"lastConsentReset":null}`

or as it is in the dev console in Chrome:

`%7B%22necessary%22%3Atrue%2C%22functional%22%3Atrue%2C%22advertising%22%3Afalse%2C%22performance%22%3Atrue%2C%22lastConsentReset%22%3Anull%7D`

I would like to use PHP to read this cookie and return the value of the key "advertising".

I have looked around to try and find a solution but they all just show how to read a cookie with just one piece of data like this:

`return $_COOKIE[ 'somecookie' ];`

I imagine I need some sort of loop to search the array I just don't know how to do it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its JSON and URL encoded, just reverse it:

```
echo json_decode(urldecode($_COOKIE['somecookie']))->advertising; // nothing as its false
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it returns nothing even when "advertising" is set to TRUE. Why would that be?

Comment: Seems there are slashes in the data in the cookie, could that cause an issue? {\"necessary\":true,\"performance\":true,\"functional\":true,\"advertising\":true,\"lastConsentReset\":null}